# Loading correctly into a NSBitmapImageRep

Tags: c++, cocoa, opencv

I am trying to display an image (with an alpha value) in a window (of size 200X200). The image is loaded into an OpenCV Mat datastructure. 
The image I am loading, looks like this:

[image]

The image i see when displayed, looks like this:

[image]

The code I am using to load the Bitmap is as follows:

```
        NSBitmapImageRep* imageRep = [[[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:nil
pixelsWide:200
    pixelsHigh:200
    bitsPerSample:8
    samplesPerPixel:4
    hasAlpha:YES
    isPlanar:NO
    colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
    bytesPerRow:(200*4)
    bitsPerPixel:32] autorelease];
    memcpy(imageRep.bitmapData,paintBuffer.data,160000);
    NSSize imageSize = NSMakeSize(200,200);
    NSImage* myImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize: imageSize] autorelease];

[myImage addRepresentation:imageRep];
    g_imageView setImage:myImage];
```

Update:

I was initially reading BGRA instead of the expected RGBA. On changing that, I just get a red version of image above, like this:

[image]

Comment: Judging by how there are blues in the image, even though the original image has only red, it looks like there is some jumbling happening with the colour channels. However, I am not sure, what is causing this pattern of horizontal lines

Comment: OpenCV stores the images in BGR (or BGRA) format, but you're interpreting it as RGB, that's why the colour is wrong.

Comment: But, if that was the case, I should have simply seen a blue coloured version of the image. There is a change in the shape of the image as well.

Comment: Yes, there's probably something else happening. The example image you've shown is 100x100 24bit image (so no alpha transparency). Yet in the example you're dealing with a 200x200 32bit image (with alpha). Where does the conversion happen? It looks to me like one line of the source image became 2 lines in what you see... Actually, is the image you posted exactly the one you used to get the output?

Comment: The image I am actually using is a 32bit  image (with alpha) which I resize to 200X200 before storing into paintBuffer. The one is posted here is not exactly that image. I tried uploading the exact image I use in my code, but I guess SO doesn't recognize 32 bit bitmaps, because it couldn't display the image.